# Twenty Questions solver

Tags: game-theory, information-theory

Consider the popular game of 20 Questions. In this game, someone chooses a secret entity $x^* \in X$ and you can ask up to 20 yes/no questions $q \in Q$ to determine the identity of $x^*$. Each question $q$ partitions $X$ into two partitions, and asking question $q$ will tell you which one contains $x^*$.

How do you select the right sequence of questions to minimize the number needed to determine the identity of $x^*$? Assume every $x \in X$ is equally likely to be chosen as $x^*$.

One approach is to select questions that partition your candidates into two parts as close in size as possible (i.e. a binary search/maximizing information gain with each step). However this doesn't seem to imply globally optimality -- e.g. you can divide $X$ into two even sets with your first question but then run out of efficient questions to ask.

Given $X$ and $Q$, how do you figure out the minimum number of questions you need to ask to determine $x^*$? What if $x^*$ was selected from some other non-uniform, known distribution?

Comment: I think [Huffmann coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) might be useful here.

Comment: The most informative question splits $X$ into two sets of equal size. If the distribution is non-uniform, ask whether $x$ is greater or smaller than the median of $X$. Then iterate.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; the set of possible questions $Q$ is already known. It may not always be possible to choose "good" questions which evenly partition $X$. Is the greedy "split as evenly as possible" strategy globally optimal? Intuitively I felt like it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This amounts to generate a binary prefix-free coding scheme (each yes/no answer is like a 0/1 bit), which in turn is equivalent to build a binary tree (each answer corresponds to a branch).

> How do you select the right sequence of questions to minimize the number needed to determine the identity

If you mean "to minimize the *average* number" of questions, then the optimal solution of this problem is the [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

(Your proposal of dividing the items in aproximately equally probably subsets is conceptually good, but it's not optimal; that would amount to build the tree starting from the root. What Huffman realized is that the tree should be built starting from the deepest leaves)

There is not a simple formula for $L=$ the exact average length of the code (or average number of questions), only the bounds

$$H\le L < H+1$$

where $H$ is the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_entropy) (in bits) of the source (probabilities of each item). 
For the case of $n$ equiprobable items, we have $H=\log_2(n)$